# Persist form data Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am new to Symfony and I follow this documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html to build a basic embed collection form.

Follow the documentation. We have Tag and Task. Task has oneToMany relation with Tag and Tag has ManyToOne relation with Task.

I also use EntityType::class in TaskType with queryBuilder to pre-populate select list of existing Task entity in database on the form.

I have completed build the form and everything work fine. However, when i submitted form instead of using existing "Task ID",a new Task with new ID but with the same data is generated. This new task ID is assigned to new Tag entity. I would want use the existing Task ID for new Tags.

Below are my classes with the YAML file:

> TaskController.php

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Task;
use AppBundle\Entity\Tag;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\TaskType;


class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $task = new Task();

        // dummy code - this is here just so that the Task has some tags
        // otherwise, this isn't an interesting example
        $tag1 = new Tag();
        $tag1->setName('tag1');

        $tag1->addTask($task);
        $task->getTags()->add($tag1);


        $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {


            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($task);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Task:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }

}
```

> Tag.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Tag
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Task
     */
    private $task;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * Set task
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Task $task
     *
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setTask(\AppBundle\Entity\Task $task = null)
    {
        $this->task = $task;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get task
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Task
     */
    public function getTask()
    {
        return $this->task;
    }


    public function addTask(Task $task)
    {

        $this->setTask($task);
    }
}
```

> TagType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;



class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tag',
        ));
    }

}
```

> Tag.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Tag:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\TagRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255

    manyToOne:
        task:
            targetEntity: Task
            inversedBy: tags
            joinColumn:
                name: task_id
                referencedColumnName: id
            cascade: [ persist ]


    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

> Task.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Task
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    protected $tags;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Task
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Get tags
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function addTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        $tag->addTask($this);
        $this->tags->add($tag);
    }


    /**
     * Remove tag
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
     */
    public function removeTag(\AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
    {
        $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
    }


    public function __toString()
    {
       return (string) $this->getDescription();
    }


}
```

> TaskType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;


use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;



class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('description', EntityType::class,array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Task',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('d');
            },));

        $builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => TagType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ));

        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'));

    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Task',
        ));
    }

}
```

> Task.orm.yaml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Task:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\TaskRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        description:
            type: string
            length: 255

    oneToMany:
        tags:
          targetEntity: Tag
          mappedBy: task
          cascade: [ persist ]

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: I don't understand, you are creating new Task with `$task = new Task();`, so of course new Task is created. Are you asking how to create `editAction` ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh i see the problem.
When you submit the form (and the new task with tags is saved), you display the same form, so user expect this to be "edit" form, but it is not.

The correct way how to do this, is to create new controller action for editing the task, for example `editAction()`, which would be similar to `newAction()`, only that the route would have parameter to identify the task (e.g. `task_id`) and in the beginning instead of creating new Task with `$task = new Task();` you would fetch the task from DB, for example:

```
$task = $this->get("doctrine")->getManager()->getRepository("AppBundle:Task")->findOneById($task_id);
```

you could also reuse the same form type.

**THEN**, you add redirect in original newAction after entity is persisted to this new edit action:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute("task_edit", array("task_id" => $task->getId()));
```

so after submitting the add form, you would be redirected to edit action, so next time the task is changed and for is submitted, the task is updated and not created new one.

Comment: Thank you for our answer. It is not exactly answer my question but your answer did give me idea how to figure it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So what I need to do is to use $form->getData() to get submitted entities (Task and Tags) and then persist them manually to the database.

```
   if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

        $description = $data->getDescription();

        $tags = new ArrayCollection();

        $tags = $data->getTags();

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $tag->addTask($description);
        }


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($tag);
        $em->flush();
    }
```